# Change the next page dynamically of a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using a `ViewPager` and displaying a lot of different `Fragments` inside it, not only in content but they use different classes as well. The list to be displayed should be changed dynamically and even though I manage to swap items around and add new ones to the adapter(and calling `notifyDataSetChanged`), if I try changing the next item it will still slide to it when using `mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);`

I am just adding a new `Fragment` between the current item and the current next one, it is displayed correctly in the adapter but as the next one was already preloaded then `getItem` in the adapter is not even called.

Is there another method "stronger" than `notifyDataSetChanged` that tells my `ViewPager` that it should get the next item again?

---

CODE SAMPLES:

The add and get item methods inside my `FragmentPagerAdapter`(only samples, not the actual code)

```
public void add(@NonNull Integer fragmentIndex) {
    mFragmentOrder.add(fragmentIndex);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    int selectedFragment = mFragmentOrder(position);
    Fragment fragment;

    switch (selectedFragment) {
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentA();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentB();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new FragmentC();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new FragmentD();
            break;
    }

    return fragment;
}
```

This is the function used to go to the next item(I don't allow swiping)

```
public void goToNext() {
    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
}
```

---

EDITS:

Edit 1: I had already tried using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead and setting the `OffscreenPageLimit` to 0, but to no avail.

Edit 2: [Solution] Using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` AND overwriting the `getItemPosition` function to return `POSITION_NONE` or the index in the appropriate cases solved the problem. For some reason even after implementing the right version of this function the normal `FragmentPagerAdapter` kept delivering the wrong `Fragment`.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Comment: I had already tried with the ``FragmentStateAdapter`` as well, it wouldn't fix the problem anyway. As I said, the ``ViewPager`` is not requerying the adapter for the new "next" slide, it just shows the one already preloaded. Trying to set the off page limit does nothing as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `FragmentPagerAdapter` assumes that the number and positions of its items remain fixed. Therefore, if you want to introduce for dynamism, you have to provide for it yourself by implementing the `getItemPosition(Object object)` method in the inherited adapter class. A very basic (but unefficient) implementation would be this:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Every time the parent view is determining whether the position of one of its child views (items) has changed, this code will force the fragment to be recreated. If you want to avoid the recreation when unnecessary, you have to include some logic in the method. Something like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition (Object object) {
    if (fragmentOrder.indexOf(object) == -1) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    } else {
        return index;
    }
}
```

Finally, pay attention to possible memory leaks by adding an `onDestroyView` method to your fragments and nullifying the views you are using.

[Here](https://medium.com/inloop/adventures-with-fragmentstatepageradapter-4f56a643f8e0) is a good discussion of these issues with the two `PagerAdapter`s.

Comment: Combining your solution with a ``FragmentStateAdapter`` did the trick. Thanks, and the article you linked is useful as well.